# error in program for playing a video in opencv

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

warning : error opening file

c:\users\vp\work\ocv\opencv\modules\highgui\src\cap_ffmpeg.cpp:454

How to remove this error?

My program :

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv\ml.h>
#include<opencv\cxcore.h>



int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
cvNamedWindow( "DisplayVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture(" E:\softwares\opencv\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\HighGUI\video-input-psnr-ssim\video\Megamind.avi ");
IplImage* frame;
while(1) {
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
if( !frame ) break;
cvShowImage( "DisplayVideo", frame );
char c = cvWaitKey(33);
if( c == 27 ) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow("DisplayVideo" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '/' or '\\', not '\'..

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture(" E:\\softwares\\opencv\\samples\\cpp\\tutorial_code\\HighGUI\\video-input-psnr-ssim\\video\\Megamind.avi ");
```